# LINQ Left Join 3 tables with OR operator

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM [CMS_MVC_PREPROD].[dbo].[T_MEMBER] m  
left outer join [CMS_MVC_PREPROD].[dbo].[T_COMPANY] c
ON m.Company_Id = c.Id
left outer join [CMS_MVC_PREPROD].[dbo].[T_ADRESSE] a  
ON m.Id = a.Member_Id OR a.Company_Id = c.Id
```

But i could not translate it to Linq

I have some trouble with this line in particular:

```
ON m.Id = a.Member_Id OR a.Company_Id = c.Id
```

EDIT: I try this query from Ehsan Sajjad

```
from m in db.Member
join c in db.T_Company on m.Company_Id equals c.Id into a
from c in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
from ta in db.T_Address
where m.Id == ta.Member_Id || ta.Company_Id == c.Id
```

But it only returns members who have an address and i want all members. Maybe it will work with a full join

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried in LINQ?

Comment: Since you are not talking to the people who have answered it is unlikely that your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ only supports equi-joins directly. You'll have to use a different query pattern:

```
from m in db.MEMBER
//add join to "c" here
from a in (
     from a db.ADRESSE
     where m.Id == a.Member_Id || a.Company_Id == c.Id
     select a).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { m, a }
```

Just a sketch. The trick is using `DefaultIfEmpty` on a subquery. Both L2S and EF can translate this to an `OUTER APPLY` which is equivalent to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I try your query but the syntax isn't correct. Are you sure that I have to use a subquery?

Comment: Yes, the syntax is not correct since this is a sketch. Did you try to understand the idea behind this? Did you make any attempt at all to fix the trivial syntax errors? If you have concrete problems I'll help you. I wont write your code for you.

Comment: Yes of course, i'm not asking for the entire code. I made several attempts but i didn't succeed. I just don't understand how to use the subquery

Comment: I fixed the totally invalid syntax and added a comment for the missing join. If you add it it should just work (or there is some other probably minor error). Try to understand the idea and less the concrete code that is here. Ask me concrete questions if you have any.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The join works but the result is like an inner join and not a left join. I have two left join in my sql suery, so I try to add a defaultEmpty to the first join but it didn't work. Finally i used a stored procedure to make it work.

Comment: Capture the SQL with SQL Profiler. That will allow you to see your mistake. You will see LEFT JOIN in the SQL. The mistake is something else. Or post the current LINQ code

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way to make it work:

```
from m in db.Member
join c in db.T_Company on m.Company_Id equals c.Id into a
from c in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
from ta in db.T_Address
where m.Id == ta.Member_Id || ta.Company_Id == c.Id
```

Comment: Your answer almost works but the query do not returns all members

Comment: @user3830047 what you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that the join works but it's an inner join not a left join.

Comment: It would return same result as your sql query